# Setting up a round robin style of SSH login in a network

Tags: ssh

I have a network of several linux/unix boxes (various ubuntu, raspian, and on OS-X box) that I have routinely log into. Generally I am on the OSX machine and I have generated a key pair that has been shared with each of the boxes and I can log into each of them using the key pair.

The problem I am having is trying to create the key pair for other boxes for when I need to copy files directly between those boxes, since most of the time the MBP is on wifi and the connection to slow to move large files.

For the sake of a simple example, my MBP is computer A. Ubuntu #1 is computer B and Ubuntu #2 is computer C.

Using key pairs:
A can log into B
A can log into C

But B cannot log into C nor can C log into B

The error I get is a <s>"public key" error</s> **permission denied (public key).**

Everywhere I search regarding this error seems to be the case where multiple keys are used to sign into different boxes.

The only way I can think of to possibly do this is to create the same key pair and put both the same public and private keys on each computer, but that seems like a security risk having them both in the one location.

edit:

So this is what happens in more detail (sorry, I should have been more thorough)

From A (MBP) I log into B (bbox), but can not log into C (sun) (from B).

From A, I can log into C, but not into B (from C).

```
madivad@bbox:~$ ssh sun
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I can't push the public key either for the same reason:

```
madivad@bbox:~$ ssh-copy-id sun
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/madivad/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.
        (if you think this is a mistake, you may want to use -f option)

madivad@bbox:~$ ssh-copy-id -f sun
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/madivad/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
Permission denied (publickey).
madivad@bbox:~$
```

So let's generate it again (which I have done countless times):

```
madivad@bbox:~$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/madivad/.ssh/id_rsa):
/home/madivad/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/madivad/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/madivad/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:<removed> madivad@bbox
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|       So        |
|  beautiful it's |
|   a shame to    |
|    remove it    |
|    (although    |
|       it's      |
|   probably not  |
|     required)   |
+----[SHA256]-----+
madivad@bbox:~$ ssh-copy-id sun
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/madivad/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Permission denied (publickey).
madivad@bbox:~$
```

I seem to be going around in circles

Comment: If you're using `ssh-agent` with agent forwarding, logging into B from A would allow you to continue by logging into C from B.

Answer (score 0):

> The error I get is a "public key" error.

With such precision in how you report errors, all I can say is that you made a mistake somewhere when generating or deploying the keys.

What you should do is generate a key pair on each machine, by running the command

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then, for each pair of machines such that you want to be able to use the key on X to log into machine Y, run the following command on machine X:

```
ssh-copy-id X
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles, I have updated my question if you'd take another look.

Comment: @Madivad Please follow all the steps in [the “Troubleshooting” section of the ssh tag wiki](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info). If that doesn't help, edit your question to confirm the checks you made and post the debugging information.

Comment: I found it. Thanks for the link, I had been there before but when I went and checked the permissions (which were ok), I just decided to delete almost everything and start again. I had various key files in there that I'd installed  over time (I've done several network re-configs). For whatever reason they don't conflict with the MBP, but they did with other servers. Once removed I pushed the new key over and all was good. Basically there were extra public keys in the directory that were causing the issue. Cheers for the nudge